# symfony php8 security attribute repeat workaround?

Tags: php, symfony, attributes, php-8

I have some code that looks like this::

```
#[Security('thing.getUserId() == user.getUserId()', statusCode: 403)] 
#[Security('thing.someCheck() == false', statusCode: 410, message: 'Something something')]
...
public function controllerMethod(...)
{ ...
```

I'm unable to use these multiple security attributes, because the Security configuration doesn't have the \Attribute::IS_REPEATABLE flag. And I can't use the expression, because it doesn't offer the different statusCodes I require. I'd like to keep the logic in the attributes.

Comment: Looking through some of the [discussions](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/46912), I wouldn't be surprised if `Security` gets deprecated and removed eventually. The bundle it comes was [marked as read-only](https://github.com/sensiolabs/SensioFrameworkExtraBundle/blob/master/src/Configuration/Security.php) recently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the following security check as a workaround:

```
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\AccessDeniedHttpException;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\GoneHttpException;

public function controllerMethod(...) {
    if (thing.getUserId() == user.getUserId()) {
        throw new AccessDeniedHttpException("Access denied");
    }

    if (thing.someCheck() == false) {
        throw new GoneHttpException("Something something");
    }
}
```

Comment: `thing.getUserId()` does not look like valid PHP code to me

Comment: @NicoHaase I just took the condition from the original question, it's supposed that the author changes the logic, meaning this line: `#[Security('thing.getUserId() == user.getUserId()', statusCode: 403)]`